# Windows 10 DNS setting sporadically reverts to old (incorrect) address

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, dns

This is a problem that occurs often (but not always) on my Windows 10 laptop... I turn it on and connect to a wi-fi network; and I get the icon that means "connected, but no internet". When this happens, I go to the "Network connections" and look at the Wi-fi properties. Under TCP/IPv4, I find that it is set to "Obtain IP address automatically"; but the DNS server address has reverted to an old (and incorrect) DNS address that I had once entered manually. I click the box that says "Obtain DNS server address automatically", click OK, and then all is fine -- until this happens again.

How can I get my system to forget that old, wrong DNS address once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To clear your DNS cache:**

1. On your keyboard, press Win+X to open the WinX Menu.
2. Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
3. Run the following command:

   ipconfig /flushdns

If the command succeeds, the system returns the following message:

```
Windows IP configuration successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

Comment: @naarzan This will purge the DNS cache but not change the configured DNS server

Comment: Before you setup your DNS as Static or Dynamic from your PC run this command, to clear the "cash" if something stuck it will solve that, check this documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794721(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I did this (@benjamin hastings: *after* I had reconfigured TCP/IP so that it works correctly) and received the message you indicated. Since this solution looks very promising, I went ahead and accepted this answer. You can be sure I will angrily uncheck it if the problem recurs :-) in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with an Windows 8 computer that would not let go of some old TCP/IP settings that I had set once even though it was already configured for DHCP.

I searched the registry for that IP address and deleted the value and rebooted